# Why localhost's phpmyadmin is empty with no login window?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin following the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04). Installation has completed and I have phpmyadmin inside `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and has linked to

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

But doesn't show anything (the whole page is blank with no login window) when I access to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

What could be wrong?
My os is Ubuntu14.04 and installed Apache 2.4.7.

Answer (score 0):

For those who has similar problem, please follow the steps below.
Please check error at /var/log/apache2/error.log
My error is  `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.')`

So install `sudo apt-get install php-gettext`
Then restart `sudo service apache2 restart`.